# Search categories with input field in VUE.js

Tags: vue.js, search, filter

I have a little problem, if someone could help me I would be very grateful.

I have to make a list of categories and subcategories for each category. I have to put an input field which will search through the titles of categories and subcategories, but I do not know how to do that in vue.js

For example if I have something like this

Category 1 Fruit with subcategories Banana, Apple.

Category 2 Books with subcategories Drama, Romance

If I write fruit in the search field, it should return Fruit (Banana, Apple). If I write Romance in the search field, it should return Books (Romance)

Thanks in advance!

```html
<table>
<input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search">
 <div> <p>Fruit</p> </div>
<tr v-for="fruit in fruits" :key="fruit.id">
                                
<div v-if="fruit.id == 1" >                             
<a href="Banana" target="_blank">{{fruit.name}}</a>      
</div>
<div v-if="fruit.id == 2" >                             
<a href="Apple" target="_blank">{{fruit.name}}</a>                                   </div>        
</tr>
<br>
<div> <p>Books</p> </div>
<tr v-for="book in books" :key="book.id">
                                
<div v-if="book.id == 1" >                             
<a href="Drama" target="_blank">{{book.name}}</a>      
</div>
<div v-if="fruit.id == 2" >                             
<a href="Romance" target="_blank">{{book.name}}</a>                                   </div>        
</tr>
</table>


data() {
   return {
search:'',
fruititems: [
{name:Banana, id:1},
{name:Apple}, id:2}
],
bookitems: [
{name:Drama, id:1},
{name:Romance}, id:2}
],
}}

computed:{
fruits() {
 return this.fruits.filter(fruit => 
 fruit.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()))},
books() {
 return this.books.filter(book => 
 fruit.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()))},
}
```

Comment: I only made success with searching the subcategories and showing their title, but I cant manage to search a category and show all the subcategories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive something like this ?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-vue-cli-pvbeex?file=src%2FApp.vue

to keep code history

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="search" />
    <div v-for="category in getfiltered">
      <h2>{{ category.name }}</h2>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="sub in category.subCategories">
          {{ sub }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    search: '',
    categories: [
      {
        name: 'fruits',
        subCategories: ['Apple', 'Banana'],
      },
      {
        name: 'books',
        subCategories: ['Drama', 'Romance'],
      },
    ],
  }),
  computed: {
    getfiltered: function () {
      return this.categories.filter((category) => {
        return (
          this.search.length < 2 ||
          category.name.includes(this.search) ||
          category.subCategories.find((sub) => sub.includes(this.search))
        )
      })
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: It does work, but it requires a v-bind key. I have tried with :key="category.name" and :key="category.sub". It works partially. What should I do? @mathieu

Comment: :key="category.name" should work fine because there is no name with the same name but a unique id is much better. Usualy when you get thoses data from the database they have id so use that or create some by hand. @Petunia (you should have a :Key on each v-for )

Comment: I added a :key="category.name" in the div tag and :key="sub" in the li tag. I was allowed only that, anything else would throw an error. But, if I add another category with two words, like green vegetables, when I hit space it shows me nothing. @mathieu-janio

Comment: @Petunia can you give me an reproductible exemple ? U Can use my link and give me the updates link

Comment: Thank you @mathieu I solved the problem. I added toLowerCase in the function, that was the problem